# Anonymous initialization of class with protected constructor

Tags: java, initialization, anonymous

Let's assume we have a class:

```
public class SomeClass {    
    protected SomeClass () { 
    }
}
```

In `MainClass` located in different package I tried to execute two lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeClass sac1 = new SomeClass(); 
    SomeClass sac2 = new SomeClass() {}; 
}
```

Because of `protected` constructor, in both cases I was expecting program to fail. To my suprise, anonymous initialization worked fine. Could somebody explain me why second method of initialization is ok?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your anonymous class

```
SomeClass sac2 = new SomeClass() {};
```

basically becomes

```
public class Anonymous extends SomeClass {
    Anonymous () {
        super();
    }
}
```

The constructor has no access modifier, so you can invoke it without problem from within the same package. You can also invoke `super()` because the `protected` parent constructor is accessible from a subclass constructor.

Comment: To my great surprise, the same thing happens when you use a constructor which does have arguments. In this case I think your explanation no longer stands.

Comment: @Andrei I didn't mention parameters/arguments. They play no role in the accessibility check.

Comment: Not in the accesibility check, no. But if you have a class with only a protected constructor WITH params, you have to explicitly invoke its constructor with params, from the child. I was saying that this rule seems to be skipped for anonymous classes.

Comment: @Andrei What you're saying is correct, but doesn't seem relevant here. The OP's question was about the accessibility of a constructor from an anonymous class in a different package.

Answer (score 4):

Those two little braces in

```
SomeClass sac2 = new SomeClass() {};
```

invoke a lot of automatic behavior in Java. Here's what happens when that line is executed:

1. An anonymous subclass of `SomeClass` is created.
2. That anonymous subclass is given a default no-argument constructor, just like any other Java class that is declared without a no-argument constructor.
3. The default no-argument constructor is defined with visibility `public`
4. The default no-argument constructor is defined to call `super()` (which is what no-arg constructors always do first).
5. The `new` command calls the no-argument constructor of this anonymous subclass and assigns the result to `sac2`.

The default no-argument constructor in the anonymous subclass of `SomeClass` has access to the `protected` constructor of `SomeClass` because the anonymous subclass is a descendant of `SomeClass`, so the call to `super()` is valid. The `new` statement calls this default no-argument constructor, which has `public` visibility.

Answer (score 3):

The first line fails, because `SomeClass`'s constructor is `protected` and `MainClass` is not in `SomeClass`'s package, and it isn't subclassing `MainClass`.

The second line succeeds because it is creating an anonymous subclass of `SomeClass`.  This anonymous inner class subclasses `SomeClass`, so it has access to `SomeClass`'s `protected` constructor.  The default constructor for this anonymous inner class implicitly calls this superclass constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
SomeClass sac2 = new SomeClass() {};
```

creates an instance of a new class which extends `SomeClass`. Since `SomeClass` defines a protected constructor without arguments, a child class may call this implicitly in its own constructor which is happening in this line.