# Create a JsonProcessingException

Tags: java, junit, jackson, mockito

I'm trying to create a JsonProcessingException to be thrown by a mock object.

```
when(mapper.writeValueAsString(any(Object.class))).thenThrow(new JsonProcessingException("Error"));
```

However I'm unable to create a JsonProcessingException object as all the constructors are protected. How do I get around this?

Comment: why don't you create a new class namely `MyJsonProcessingException` and inherit `JsonProcessingException` class?

Comment: @R9J Why create a class when you don't have to?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

how about you create an anonymous exception of type JsonProcessingException

```
when(mapper.writeValueAsString(any(Object.class))).thenThrow(new JsonProcessingException("Error"){});
```

The {} braces does the trick. This is much better since it is not confusing to the reader of the test code.

Comment: this will do the trick (code will compile), but at the same time will result in `Checked exception is invalid for this method!`. Real solution will involve extending ObjectMapper in your test method and passing that to the SUT

Comment: im a bit confused, what is the backets doing?

Comment: @Robbo_UK It creates an anonymous class which extends `JsonProcessingException`.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073047/anonymous-initialization-of-class-with-protected-constructor

Comment: While it might do the same thing behind the scenes, the `doThrow/when` syntax suggested @albin-p-babu is cleaner.

Comment: I'm seeing the following error when I try this:
`unreported exception com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 20):

How about throwing one of the known direct subclasses instead?

for [v1.0](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonProcessingException.html)

```
Direct Known Subclasses:
JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, JsonParseException
```

for [v2.0](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException.html)

```
Direct Known Subclasses:
JsonGenerationException, JsonParseException
```

Comment: this does not work at all, nor should it. JsonProcessingException is a checked exception, meaning that all subclasses of JsonProcessingException are checked exceptions as well

Answer (score 16):

This one worked for me which allowed to throw JsonProcessingException itself

```
doThrow(JsonProcessingException.class).when(mockedObjectMapper).writeValueAsString(Mockito.any());
```

Answer (score 8):

I came across this issue today also.  The simplest and cleanest solution I came up with was to create and throw a mock JsonProcessingException

```
when(mapper.writeValueAsString(any(Object.class)))
    .thenThrow(mock(JsonProcessingException.class));
```

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same issue today. You can use:

```
Mockito.when(mockObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(Mockito.any())).thenThrow(JsonProcessingException.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `thenAnswer` and create an anonymous class from `JsonProcessingException`

```
when(mapper.writeValueAsString(any(Object.class))).thenAnswer(x-> {throw new JsonProcessingException(""){};});
```